# Side borders on meta sites

Tags: support, design

Just noticed that meta sites have vertical lines on both sides of the page.

> [image: meta]

Which don’t exist on main sites:

> [image: main]

What’s the purpose of such design separation among main and meta sites?

Comment: I only noticed this on SO so far. From the other sites I looked at, it looks like the borders are on both meta and the main site.

Answer (score 3):

What you can't quite see due to your page width and because you have the left navigation turned off is that the background color on Meta is different than the foreground - it's grey next to white. The colors are similar enough, though, that we need a line to separate them.

[image: Full width view of Meta Stack Overflow with left navigation. Shows vertical line on both sides of page.]

On Main, the background and foreground are both white, so there's no need for a vertical line, though we do have one on the left if you have the left navigation turned on. This makes a clear separation between the navigation and the content.

[image: Full width view of Stack Overflow with left navigation. Shows vertical line on left side only.]

When the left navigation is turned off, there's no reason to have a line separating one white area from another. The content creates that optically on its own.

This isn't really a meta vs main issue, though. It's all about the colors of the sidebars vs the content. If they're too similar, as on Meta Stack Overflow, they get a line to give some separation. If they have sufficient contrast or are the same color, they don't unless the left navigation is active, and then the line is there to separate the content of the two spaces.

If you look around at the different sites that have the unified themes, you'll see that it's customized on a per-site basis.

Comment: On my iPad the right vertical line (when left nav is visible) is placed almost [near the screen edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrQA9.jpg). I.e. hard to see it at all.